# send file from nestjs

Tags: spring, multipartform-data, nestjs

I`m using react js (frontEnd), nodejs(backend), also java spring endpoints which connects through proxy with nodejs.
I have problem with sending formData(file) from nodejs to spring

I send from react js, request body as multipart/form-data array of files. It correctly comes to nest js. Via http request I have to send it to the Spring, like form-data

```
createApplication(application: any, files: any) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    console.log(files)
    formData.append('application', JSON.stringify(application));

    files.map(file => formData.append('file1', file
    ));
    return this.http.post(
      `${BASIC_URL}/application`,
        formData,
      { headers: formDataHeader },
    );
}
```

shows me error

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at Function.DelayedStream.create (/Users/user/workProjects/b2bsc-backend/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.append (/Users/user/workProjects/b2bsc-backend/node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js:45:37)
    at FormData.append (/Users/user/workProjects/b2bsc-backend/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:74:3)
    at files.map.file (/Users/user/workProjects/b2bsc-backend/dist/b2b/b2b.service.js:50:36)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at B2bService.createApplication (/Users/user/workProjects/b2bsc-backend/dist/b2b/b2b.service.js:50:15)
    at B2bController.createApplication (/Users/user/workProjects/b2bsc-backend/dist/b2b/b2b.controller.js:30:32)
    at /Users/user/workProjects/b2bsc-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:36:29
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I want to get this file in my java side on controller

````
   @PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE } )
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<Object> createApplication(@RequestParam(value = "file1") MultipartFile[] files,
                                             @RequestParam String application,
            UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws IOException {
}```
````

Comment: Hi! Did you found any solution or workaround?

Comment: Hi there! Did somebody found solution of this issue?